# What is the difference between static methods in a Non static class and static methods in a static class?

Tags: c#, oop, static, static-methods, non-static

I have two classes Class A and ClassB:

```
static class ClassA
{
    static string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "I am a Static Method";
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    static string SomeMethod()
    {
        return "I am a Static Method";
    }
}
```

I want to know what is the difference between `ClassA.SomeMethod();` and `ClassB.SomeMethod();`

When they both can be accessed without creating an instance of the class, why do we need to create a static class instead of just using a non static class and declaring the methods as static?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The *only* difference is that static methods in a nonstatic class **cannot be [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)**.

---

In other words, this is invalid:

```
class Test
{
    static void getCount(this ICollection<int> collection)
    { return collection.Count; }
}
```

whereas this is valid:

```
static class Test
{
    static void getCount(this ICollection<int> collection)
    { return collection.Count; }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

A static class can only contain static members.

A static method ensures that, even if you were to create multiple classB objects, they would only utilize a single, shared SomeMethod function.

Technically, there's no difference, except that ClassA's SomeMethod **must** be static.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a non-static class containing only static methods, you could create an instance of that class. But you can't use that instance meaningfully. NB: when you don't define a constructor, the compiler adds one for you.

A static class does not have a constructor, so you can't create an instance of it. Also the compiler gives an error when you add an instance method to it (where you meant a static method).

See also [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

Comment: You can however, define a static constructor in a static class that gets called once only, upon first usage?

Comment: @PiotrKula yes that is true. A static constructor is called automatically "*before* first use"

Answer (score 1):

A static method belongs to the class and a non-static method belongs to an object of a class. That is, a non-static method can only be called on an object of a class that it belongs to. A static method can access only static members. A non-static method can access both static and non-static members because at the time when the static method is called, the class might not be instantiated (if it is called on the class itself). In the other case, a non-static method can only be called when the class has already been instantiated. A static method is shared by all instances of the class. Whenever a method is called in C++/Java/C#, an implicit argument (the ‘this’ reference) is passed along with/without the other parameters. In case of a static method call, the ‘this’ reference is not passed as static methods belong to a class and hence do not have the ‘this’ reference.

Comment: How can we call a static method from on an object of the class, plz give me an example

Comment: " A static method can however be called both on the class as well as an object of the class." I believe this statement is wrong.