# What's the use of private constructor in Java?

Tags: java

I want to know that how private constructor is useful in Java.
What are the different ways to use private constructor in Java?

Comment: When you don't want someone to make an instance of your class (by calling the constructor at least).

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private

Comment: @R Martinho Fernandes i want answer of this question with respect to C++ also...

Comment: Then you need to alter your question. You're only asking for a Java scenario.

Comment: @AmrutDange, Well C++ provides an alternative solution with free functions instead of utility classes, so that one's gone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of making constructor private in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062560/what-is-the-use-of-making-constructor-private-in-a-class)

Answer (score 44):

private constructor is off course to restrict  instantiation of the class.

Actually a good use of private constructor is in Singleton Pattern. here's an example

```
public class ClassicSingleton {
   private static ClassicSingleton instance = null;
   private ClassicSingleton() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
   public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ClassicSingleton();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

this way you can ensure that only **one instance** of class is active.

Other uses can be to create a **utility class**, that only contains static methods.

For, more analysis you can look into other Stack overflow answers

[Can a constructor in Java be private?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816123/can-a-constructor-in-java-be-private)

[What is the use of making constructor private in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062560/what-is-the-use-of-making-constructor-private-in-a-class)

[private constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648602/private-constructor)

Answer (score 9):

As other answers mentioned, common uses include the **singleton pattern**, internal **constructor chaining** and one more:

Java doesn't support what in C# (for example) is known as a "static class" - in other words, a **utility class**. A utility class is a helper class that's supposed to contain only static members. (`Math` and `System` are such cases in Java.) It doesn't make sense for them to be instantiated in any way.

In C#, making a class static makes it implicitly both final/sealed and abstract. In Java, there is no such keyword and you can't make a class final *and* abstract. So if you had such a utility class, you'd make it final and give it a private constructor that's never called.

Comment: BTW The new approach to static class is `enum`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you give an example?

Comment: `public enum Utility {; public static void fn1() {} }`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Wow. Haven't seen that before. Definitely interesting.

Answer (score 8):

**private constructor** is used when you want that this class can't be intitalise from outside

**Uses**


**Case 1:** When creating sington classs

```
public class SingletonClass {

    public static SingletonClass singletonClass;

    private SingletonClass() {
    }

    public static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        if(singletonClass == null) {
            singletonClass = new SingletonClass();
        }
        return singletonClass;
    }
}
```

In this case only intialization is done by getInstance method. No one can create Object of SingletonClass form outside.

**Case 2:** when you don't want any instance of object like in util classes

```
public final class Util {

    private Util() {
    }
}
```

In util class all methods are static so no need of creation of its object so in that case private constructor is used

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323022/static-class-vs-class-with-private-constructor-and-all-static-properties-and-me I think with static util class, you do not need to create private contructor.

Comment: @ZuzooVn in java you cann't create class as static. The question you mentioned in the comment is based upon C# language

Comment: ***"No one can create Object of SingletonClass from outside."*** What if outside do SingletonClass s = SingletonClass.getInstance(); ? I think the benefit in your example is to prevent multiple SingletonClass instances exist.

Answer (score 6):

Some reasons where you may need private constructor:

to prevent instantiation outside of the object, in the following cases:

1. singleton
2. factory method
3. static-methods-only (utility) class
4. constants-only class

You can also refer this code:

```
public class MySingletonEx 
{

    private static MySingletoneEx instance = new MySingletonEx("This takes a string");;

    private MySingletonEx(final String myString)
    {
        // This is a private constructor
    }

    public static MySingletonEx getInstance() 
    {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The use of a private constructor stops it being created by anything 'outside' the object. This is often used in things like the [***singleton***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern, where it tries to ensure only one instance of the class exists.

[***This link also***](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=40) offers some good descriptions...

Answer (score 2):

As an addition to the other answers:

If you want to create a singleton class, you need to hide the constructor, so it can only be called internally.

Comment: Yes, see the other 50 answers telling you the same thing :-D

Answer (score 1):

IMHO some usage are

1. in Singleton
2. From another constructor ..

Answer (score 1):

You may not want users of the class to instantiate it directly but instead use a convenient static method instead, for a very contrived builder example:

```
public FooBuilder {

    private FooBuilder(FooBar bar) {
        ...
    }

    public static FooBuilder using(FooBar bar) {
        return new FooBuilder(bar);
    }

}
```

You then use it by invoking the static method:

```
FooBuilder.using(bar) // further chained methods etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you don't want a particular class to be instantiated ever.

Answer (score 0):

Another use of private constructors is to make sure that only a limited set of instances of a class exists.

For example:

```
public class Color
{
    public static final Color red = new Color("red");
    public static final Color yellow = new Color("yellow");
    public static final Color blue= new Color("blue");

    private Color(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

This usage has mostly been supplanted by Java enumerations, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the uses of private constructors.

1. Ability to design a singleton pattern(only one instance of the object is shared among all the objects).

2.To limit the number of instance creation.

3.To prevent subclassing.