# How do you ensure a class is instantiated only from within a specific class?

Tags: java

Let's say I have a `ParkingMeter` class and a `ParkingSlip` class. ParkingSlips should only be created from within the `ParkingMeter` class, but `ParkingSlips` should be accessible by an external class called `Car` (so you can check if each car has paid for parking).

Is there a way to ensure `ParkingSlips` can only be created from within ParkingMeter but is still accessible to other classes?

Comment: Use a private constructor for ParkingSlips. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342815/what-is-the-use-of-private-constructor-in-java

Comment: Make ParkingSlips a private inner class to ParkingMeter. Then write a getter method to get the ParkingSlips (not a setter). Have Car call the getter in ParkingMeter

Comment: Yes, of course. You can see Inner Class:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html. You can make the ParkingSlip  as the inner class of ParkingMeter. Car can get the  ParkingSlip  object through getter.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to make `ParkingSlip` an inner class, put the two classes in the same package and make `ParkingSlip`'s constructor package-private. It won't stop other classes in the same package from creating parking slips, but it will stop evildoers in other packages.

```
package parking;

public class ParkingSlip {
    ParkingSlip() {
    }
}

public class ParkingMeter {
    public ParkingSlip getSlip() {
        return new ParkingSlip();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest way is to make ParkingSlip public inner static class of ParkingMeter and give it a private constructor.

```
public class ParkingMeter {
    public static class ParkingSlip {
        private ParkingSlip() {
        }
    }
}
```

A less safe, but more useable, way is to give default (aka "package") visibility to the constructor and have ParkingMeter in the same package, but any other class from the same package - even from a different project - will have access to the constructor.

Note that whichever way you go, reflection can circumvent it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is a way to check who called a constructor or method: 
by **examining the current stack trace**.
 Not that I'd recommend it, but hey, it works:

```
public ParkingSlip() {

    // get the current stack trace
    // element 0: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace
    // element 1: this constructor
    // element 2: the class/method calling this constructor
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

    // verify that it was indeed the ParkingMeter who invoked the constructor 
    if (!ParkingMeter.class.getName().equals(stackTrace[2].getClassName())) {
        throw new IllegalAccessError("Restricted access, only ParkingMeter is allowed to create instances");
    }
}
```

A **cleaner solution**, which resticts constructor access at compile time (the solution above only checks at runtime) is to

- place `ParkingMeter` and `ParkingSlip` (only those two) in a dedicated package
- leave both classes `public`
- make the constructor(s) for `ParkingSlip` 'friendly' (neither `private`, nor `protected`, nor `public`)

This ensures that the `ParkingSlip` constructors can only be accessed by classes in the same package, and as `ParkingMeter` is the only other class in that package, you've got what you want.

```
public class ParkingSlip {

   // 'friendly' constructor
   ParkingSlip() {
   }
}
```